# HBase-Master Service

Tags: hbase

I can't start HBase-Master's service when the zookeeper service is running. So, when I get the HBase shell and execute a command, I get this error :

```
ERROR [Main] client.HConnectionManager$HConnection /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this [link](http://hbase.apache.org/book/zookeeper.html) to solve your problem

> To point HBase at an existing ZooKeeper cluster, one that is not
>   managed by HBase, set HBASE_MANAGES_ZK in conf/hbase-env.sh to false